# How to update contact object from related junction object?

Tags: apex, trigger, junction-object

I created a junction object called `Sponsorship__c` and have a many-to-many relationship. It is related to Contact through a master-detail relationship and I have another custom object called `Sponsored_Child__c` which also has a relationship with `Sponsorship__c`.

What I need to do is create a trigger that updates a Contact field once a new Sponsorship is been created or updated. That field is `Child_Names__c` and once a Sponsorship is created, the first name(`First_Name__c` of `Sponsored_Child__c`) of the Child is concatenated to the field `Child_Names__c` of Contact.

Comment: Hi user42387, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you. SFSE is a Q&A forum where we look to help each other by asking and answering questions about real problems or errors with our code. Posting requests to write code for you generally get closed. Have you gone thru the trigger module in Trailhead?

Answer (score 1):

One of the things I like to do is add formula fields to my Junction objects to simplify things. So the first step would be to make a field on Sponsorship__c; I'll call it: Sponsored_Child_Name__c.

**Formula:** 
Sponsored_Child__c.First_Name__c

Another very important thing to keep in mind is bulkification:

**Pseudo Code**

```
trigger triggerName on Sponsorship__c (events) {
if (event) { // trigger.isUpdate, trigger.isBefore, etc
Map<Id, Sponsorship__c> contactToSponsorship = new Map<Id, Sponsorship__c>();
Lisit<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();

for (Sponsorship__c s : trigger.new) {
contactToSponsorship.put(s.contact__c, s);
}

for (Contact c : [SELECT Child_Names__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contactToSponsorship.keySet()]) {
c.Child_Names__c += contactToSponsorship.get(c.Id).Sponsored_Child_Name__c;
contactsToUpdate.add(c);
}

update contactsToUpdate;
}
```

That should get you **close**.